# pstricks cut of psplot

Tags: pstricks, graphs

I am working on a presentation with some functions plotted.

Unfortunately my graphs are above my `\psgrid`. How can I cut them automatically?

This is my code:

```
 \begin{figure}
 \psset{unit=0.7, linewidth=0.7\pslinewidth, mathLabel=false}
 \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3, -4) (3, 4)
 \psgrid[griddots=5, subgriddiv=0, gridlabels=0pt](-3, -4)(3, 4)
 \psplot[algebraic, plotstyle=line, plotpoints=500, linecolor=red]{-3}{3}{x^3}
 \end{pspicture}
 \end{figure}
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image: picture]

Comment: Provide us with a complete but minimal source code that can be used to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity sorry I had a mistake in my code. Now it should work

Comment: Use `pspicture*` instead of `pspicture`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for emergency purpose.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-4)(3,4)
\psgrid[griddots=5,subgriddiv=0,gridlabels=0pt](-3,-4)(3,4)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3, -4)(3, 4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\rput(0,0){\begin{pspicture*}(-3,-4)(3,4)\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red]{-3}{3}{x^3}\end{pspicture*}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. But why is it only for an emergency?